# Vuejs javascript module import "TypeError: not a constructor"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, vuejs2, prototype

I am trying to load this javascript module https://github.com/amendoa/fullPageScrollPureJS

In my main.js I am trying to import a script from my asset folder.
I saw a few different stackoverflow posts on this but I just couldn't seem to get it to work.
I tried both import and require.

main.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import * as fullScroll from "./assets/full-page-scroll.js";
// let fullScroll = require("./assets/full-page-scroll.js");

Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$FullScroll', { value: fullScroll });
```

In my App.vue

```js
    LaunchFP() {
      console.log(this.$FullScroll);
      new this.$FullScroll({
        mainElement: "main",
        displayDots: true,
        dotsPosition: "left",
        animateTime: 0.7,
        animateFunction: "ease"
      });
      // console.log(typeof this.$FullScroll)


    }
```

I get the following error.

> [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: this.$FullScroll is not a constructor"

Comment: Unless you've modified it, [full-page-scroll.js](https://github.com/amendoa/fullPageScrollPureJS/blob/8e3454409904f4ca3815a4234691362b2ff75bb3/app/assets/javascript/full-page-scroll.js) doesn't export anything, it just attaches to `window.fullScroll`

Comment: @Matt How would I export the module? Or Use it?

Comment: you can already just call `new fullPage()` since it's attached to `window`. But I would suggest you find something newer that uses modules. Or perhaps fork it yourself. Either way, attaching to `window` is not the right way